# curl: (35) Encountered end of file puppet

Tags: puppet, nexus, puppet-enterprise

I am using puppet-archive https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-archive to download jar from nexus repository.

/puppetmaster-devteam-starter_kit/control-repo/site/role/manifests/getnexusjar.pp

```
class role::getnexusjar {

  include profile::getjarfromnexus
}
```

/puppetmaster-devteam-starter_kit/control-repo/site/profile/manifests/getjarfromnexus.pp

```
class profile::getjarfromnexus {
  include '::archive'

$test_jar_dir = [ '/home/test/', '/home/test/jar/', ]

  file { $test_jar_dir:
    ensure => 'directory',
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'wheel',
    mode   => '0750',
 }

  archive::nexus { '/home/test/jar/test-fileprocess-workflow-1.0.0.jar':
    ensure     => present,
    extract_path  => '/home/test/jar',   
    url        => 'https://nexus.testmonitoring.com/repository/test-repo/com/test/fileprocess/test-fileprocess-workflow/1.0.0/test-fileprocess-workflow-1.0.0.jar',
    username   => "testuser",
    password   => "asdfghfgh",
    gav        => 'com.test.fileprocess:test-fileprocess-workflow:1.0.0',
    repository => 'test-repo',
    packaging  => 'jar',
    extract    => false,
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Execution of '/usr/bin/curl https://nexus.testmonitoring.com/repository/test-repo/com/test/file/test-fileprocess-workflow/1.0.0/test-fileprocess-workflow-1.0.0.jar/service/local/artifact/maven/content?g=com.test.file&a=test-fileprocess-workflow&v=1.0.0&r=test-repo&p=jar -o /tmp/test-fileprocess-workflow-1.0.0.jar_20180118-30748-1j50ff9 -fsSL --max-redirs 5 --user testuser:asdfghfgh’ returned 35: curl: (35) Encountered end of file
```

Comment: The URL is invalid.

Comment: I made changes in the url while posting it here due to security issues.

Comment: When the catalog containing the resource presented is applied to the target node, one of the effects is to run a `curl` command to obtain a JAR from the repository.  That command is emitting the error message you see and exiting with nonzero status.  The particular error message makes me suspect a problem on the repository side, but it could be that your resource parameters are wrong in some repository-specific way.  In either case, I'm not sure we can render any specific help.